# Internet Explorer and Chrome recognize my software as a virus

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, malware-detection

I developt a nice software and I wanted to publish it online, I make a nice website for the download, but it seem that Internet Explorer and Chrome recognize my software as a virus and post a download warning to the users how want's to install it, I think it's using SmartScreen for the microsoft explorer and the chrome browser info said [this info](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=iw&p=ib_download_scan&answer=99020)

can anyone suggest me please what to do? 
how can I make my software download approve?

I'm new with develeoping so if it's a stupid question I'm sorry...

thank you all

Comment: I just saw a good post about making the SmartScreen filter happy here: https://www.blurity.com/blog/2012/07/13/how-not-using-internet-explorer-put-me-out-of-touch-and-cost-me-dearly/

Comment: I read it, It's extactly the same happen to me, I don't have the money to spent now for signing the software but thank you for the suggestion...

Answer (score 2):

The browsers assume it is a malicious software because of no digital signing. Which IDE are you using? If Visual Studio, this option is readily available. Digitally sign your software with corporation name as "Personal" or "Test" or "For Download" or whatever.

If you are using some other IDE, you can always download something on Google and then digitally sign the software. Once this step is done, most browsers and anti-virus software would not classify your software as malicious.

P.S. You might have to make an account with the digital signing software. If using VS, it asks for your further credentials as well.

Cheers!

Comment: Hello Nathan822, thank you for your help, I'm using VS 2010 can you send me guide how to sign my software please... thank you very much your very kind...

Comment: Hi Naor,
Like I said, you will need to verify your credentials. You have to apply for a license to get a software publishing certificate. You will also have to pledge not to distribute viruses, malware, or any other harmful code. The details are given on Microsoft's website. 

The URL is: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361(v=vs.85).aspx#Criteria_for_Individ

Follow the instructions and get your own digital signature. Then publish good software for life! :)

Hope this helped you. Cheers!!!